# Is it possible to do Android development on a MIPS computer?

Tags: android, development, mips

On a computer with a MIPS architecture (e.g. a [Lemotoe Yeeloong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemote#Netbook_computers)), running GNU/Linux, is it possible to install and run the necessary tools for developing Android apps for deployment on smartphones?

Comment: I don't have enough for a full answer, but I don't see why it would be much different from any other cross-compiling situation. Lots of smartphone development is done by cross-compiling to ARM on Intel or AMD64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't own a MIPS system, but would think so<sup>1</sup> -- a key requirement of android dev is the `adb` utility, which turns up [in the Debian MIPS distribution](http://packages.debian.org/search?arch=mips&keywords=android-tools-adb).

That's not everything that's required, and android doesn't use a normal java SDK either.  [Their site](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) annoyingly just lists 32-bit `glibc` as a requirement for the "Linux" version of the ADT bundle (that's everything), implying it was compiled for x86 machines (it runs on 64-bit with 32-bit libs).

However, you are in luck, because **Android is totally open source**, including the dev tools:

http://source.android.com/

There are build instructions there, etc.  I think that little laptop will have its hands full -- have fun!

---

<sup>1. I believe Android runs on MIPS devices, although of course that doesn't help you here.</sup>

Comment: `adb` is only one tool among many. Gcc should be easy. But the rest… if nobody's tried it before, I doubt that it'll work without some major hunting of non-portable constructs in millions of lines of code.